# Why is my pineapple plant not flowering. Now 5 1/2 years. Looks healthy and new leaves keep growing but no flower. Will it never bloom now

Tags: diagnosis, fruit-trees, flowering, pineapple

Should I give up on this 51/2 year pineapple plant?

Comment: Potted pineapple plants may not always flower reliably, is your plant potted? In which US hardiness zone are you and is your plant in- or outdoors? Your question contains not enough information for a good answer.

Comment: It’s an indoor plant and I live in CT. It’s potted in large pot in front of a slider that gets daylite and sun daily. New leaves continue to grow and they look healthy. Is it possible that no pineapple will grow after this long period of time ?

Answer (score 3):

If your plant doesn't want to flower by itself, you can try to stimulate it with ethylene gas. There are more ways to get this gas, but the easiest way is to use apple pieces and put them close to the rosette. [Here](https://www.growables.org/information/TropicalFruit/pineappleforcingflower.htm) are more methods described for ethylene gas production in order to stimulate flowering in *Ananas*.

Comment: I don’t have a rosette. Just leaves

Comment: With rosette I mean the middle, where the leaves come out. Where you would expect the flower to come out from.

Answer (score 2):

- Getting sunlight through glass windows is filtered light at best.. tropical plants of this nature like lots of direct sun, especially in cooler climates.
- Consider moving her just outside that glass door.
- Using apple slices may help,
- But also feed with a blooming and rooting formula (higher phosphate on the NPK rating) something like product in photo but maybe half strength and twice as often as directed to not burn it.
- Also DO NOT feed it until its been outside a week or 2 and adapted to the temperature change and feed in the evening not in the heat of the day to avoid burning it.
- As well when nightly temps are regularly getting near the 40s bring her back inside and use plant lights to continue growth all winter

[image: N-P-K 5-50-17 the middle number helps flowering and root growth..this stuff can kill a plant by burning, so use at half strength and twice as often when hot outside]